# Problem with OS X automator and python and os.system

Tags: macos, automator

If I use

```
import os
os.system("pdflatex myfile.tex")
```

from iron python it just works. If I start to Automator and use "Run shell script" switch the shell to python the same command is not executed anymore. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try full paths for both files - env and cwd are probably different.

Comment: thx that helped ! pdflatex was the bad thing. I had it in my $PATH that´s why I thought solely pdflatex was sufficient. Probably will update this question soon